React Installation using npm is throwing an error
enter image description hereI am unable to install React Vite using npm
Steps I did :

Created a new folder
Opened it in VS Code
In terminal gave the following commands
i) npm create vite@latest
ii) cd my-project-name
iii) npm install
iv) npm run dev
After giving these commands I am getting an error .

